# Spring batch 5: how to invoke a particular job from commandline?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have multiple jobs in my spring batch application. And none of the jobs are configured to Launch by default. In 4.x, i could invoke a particular job from commandline using `--spring.batch.job.names=My-JOB-1`.

Now I am migrating from spring batch 4.x to 5.x ( as part of spring boot 2.6.6 to 3.x migration).

But now the above approach does not seem to work in spring batch 5. Is this the expected behavior with spring batch 5. If it is, then what is the work around for this.

I have looked at [spring batch 5.0.3 docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html) but there is no mention of this change.

(Note: using main method or CommandLineRunner i can solve it but it looks like overkill and a generic approach)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring Batch 5 but with Spring Boot 3 (or 2.7 even). You can now run only 1 job through parameters, which has been renamed accordingly to `spring.batch.job.name`.

Comment: +1 to what @M.Deinum said. This is mentioned in migration guide of Spring Boot 3 here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#multiple-batch-jobs